# Tensorflow array of arguments for map_fn

Tags: python, tensorflow, parallel-processing

I would like to use map_fn to leverage more parallelism. I used to do it with Pool.map.

```py
p=Pool() # from multiprocessing
params=list()
params.append([arg1, arg2, arg3])
# arg1 is of size MxN (matrix, ~500x500), arg2 and arg3 are of size I and J (vectors)
# final size is conditional to the value of some booleans i.e.:
if mask[1]:
    params.append([arga,argb,argc])

result = p.map(myfunc, params)
```

I can't reproduce the same thing with tensorflow. `myfunc` now uses tensorflow primitives and produces the correct result, but I can't create a stack of parameters

I tried ragged_stack, stack, concat, nothing seem to make tf happy.
The most common error I get is that arga, argb and argc should be of same size, which is not what I want.

just stacking two is a challenge:

```py
### NOT WORKING ###
param = tf.stack([
        [[a0, b0, c0]],
        [[a1, b1, c1]]
       ])

### Proceeds but errors at map_fn
p2 = tf.ragged.stack([
    tf.ragged.stack([a0, b0, c0]),
    tf.ragged.stack([a1, b1, c1])
   ])

res = tf.map_fn(myfunc, p2)
### ValueError: TypeError: object of type 'RaggedTensor' has no len()
```

How can I stack these differently sized arguments?
My simple idea would be to make all my arguments a contiguous array that I would split manually afterwards, but this is plain ugly.

Answer (score 0):

One solution, as I mentioned in the question, is to linearize everything.

#### Serialization

This implies:

- reshape NDimensional arrays to 1D
- extract the shapes of your arguments
- concatenate your arguments. Put the shapes at the end

For the unpacking, you can use the shapes located at the end of the array (or at the beginning if you so choose)

Example:

```py
# in my case, the length of X is always fixed
lenX = tf.reduce_prod( tf.shape( item0 ))
linearize = lambda x,a,b: tf.concat([
    tf.reshape(x, lenX), a, b, 
    tf.cast(tf.shape(x), tf.float32), # note the cast
    tf.cast(tf.shape(a), tf.float32), # shape produces an int
    tf.cast(tf.shape(b), tf.float32)], axis=0)

stackedParams = tf.stack([
    linearize(item0, a0, b0),
    linearize(item1, a1, b1) # ...
])

res = tf.map_fn(myFunc, stackedParams) 
# works but myFunc has to be changed slightly, see Unpacking section
```

###### Conditional stacking

This method also allows very easily to add conditional expansion of the array. The following example adds elements to the stack by

1. linearizing our objects ( any dimensions -> 1D tensor )
2. stacking these objets ( 1D -> array of 1D = 2D )
3. concatenate with param ( 2D, 2D -> 2D )
   This happen only if the condition masks[0] is fulfilled. Otherwise it returns simply param.

```py
param = tf.cond(masks[0],
    lambda: tf.concat([param, 
                tf.stack([  linearize(item2, a2, b2), 
                            linearize(item3, a3, b3) ]) 
                          ], axis=0), 
    lambda: param )
```

#### Unpacking

Now the input of the function is one single array containing everything. We need to split it.

This implies:

1. reading the shapes and sizes of each argument (located at the end for me)
2. extracting the arguments
3. eventually reshape the arguments (in case they are not supposed to be 1D)

Example

```py
# in my case, the linearization is carried out with this layout:
# matrix, u, v, h, w, lu, lv
# with u and v 1D vectors, lu and lv their respective size
def unpack_linearized(x):
    lv = tf.cast(x[-1], tf.int32) # read size of vector v
    lu = tf.cast(x[-2], tf.int32) # read size of vector u
    w = tf.cast(x[-3], tf.int32) # number of columns in the matrix
    h = tf.cast(x[-4], tf.int32) # number of rows in the matrix
    length = h*w

    u = x[length: length+lu] 
    v = x[length+lu:length+lu+lv]
    mat = tf.reshape(x[0:-(4+lv+lu)], (h, w))
    return (mat,u,v)
```

Note: I believe what I called "Linearization" is actually Serialization. My bad. I mixed it up when thinking about having everything "on a line".

In any case, I'm still interesting in seeing other answers with better designs